# datepicker and buttonImage

Tags: jquery, datepicker

Using Jquery Datepicker, I wanted to display a calendar image next to the input field using the buttonImage setting... Everytime the image is misplaced... is it because of the size of my image? (32x32)

I tried to place it well after with something like that :

```
$("img.ui-datepicker-trigger").css("margin-left", "3%");
$("img.ui-datepicker-trigger").css("margin-top", "5%");
```

But the input is moving with the image and the height position is still the same (the image is too high comparing to the input text postion).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the vertical-alignment of the image.

```
$("img.ui-datepicker-trigger").css("vertical-align", "middle");
```

Comment: much better indeed but this time the image is a little bit too low comparing to the input field... should I change the size of the image?.. it is bad because i can see that the image and the input text have the same height... but now it is just a little low

Comment: That is an issue with the images height, try setting vertical-align middle on the input also.